# Is there a known process for converting a Java Struts 1 application to Grails

Tags: grails, struts1

I have worked with Grails in the past and am very familiar with it.  I am inheriting a legacy application that was built in Struts 1.  There are some plans for immediate improvements and talk of moving to a more modern framework long-term.

For the long-term 'Spring' has been talked about, but I was thinking a transition to Grails might be a viable option.  Is there a grails-struts plug that could help with the transition or is there some other recommended process for converting the Struts paradigm into the Grails paradigm?

Comment: I doubt it; there's really not much of in the way of transition points because of how S1 is architected and generally used.

Comment: move to micronaut already.